# Add profile image to bootstrap navbar dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a user dropdown menu aligned right. When the user has a picture added, I would like to show a small thumbnail next to the users name. This is already done, however I think it is implemented in a flawed way.

When the viewport size shrinks, the image (as it is now) is put on the collapsed list of menu items at the bottom - which shouldn't happen. It should either disappear or stay with the users name.

Also I would like to have the picture clickable and 'grouped' with the user name.

I have made a test navbar of my code here:
https://nkhs.dk/navbar/navbar.html

Can you suggest a change to make this happen?

Regards, Niels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It should either disappear or stay with the users name.

To disappear it use the `.hidden-*` class.

e.g if you want to disappear this image on widths <768px, you would use class `.hidden-xs`.

For more: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: Okay, that's a good start! How about making it clickable together with the text?

Comment: You probably do that by wrapping the `<a>` tag with the `<img>` tag and then apply some custom CSS if that sounds crooked.

Comment: I solved it by putting the <img> tag just before the user name. That is inside the <a> and inside the first <ul> and <li>-tags. Styled it with: height: 50px; line-height: 40px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;